# Modify the Chinese date localization in the quick settings of Flyme 8.0.0.0A Stable (SystemUI.apk modification)

Tags: device-firmware, localization, quick-settings, meizu, flyme-os

I translated the firmware Flyme 8.0.0.0A Stable (RU & UA) for Meizu Note 9 and Meizu 8X, but I can’t kill the Chinese in the quick settings:

[image]

The fact is that China’s events are taking place there - the usual date, for example, if you translate from Chinese “己亥 年 十月 廿六” - “October 26.”

Who can help remove this problem from the quick settings? Or at least tell me where to look in [SystemUI.apk](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Dgmxy0ilAr2ALfDXGqn19FjzxgRtWYYW), I suspect that somewhere in the Smali code. Thanks.

Comment: That setting depends on the locale. If you simply translated parts of the UI but didn't setup a proper locale it will keep the Chinese text for data. I'm also using the Chinese ROM and an app to add the intended locale and the date shows up in the locale's language.

Comment: Thanks, but of course I apply localization through morlocal2, because I add to SystemUI.apk folders: "/res/values_ru" and "/res/values_uk", files in folder "/res/values" I do not change. English is the default lang. The hieroglyphs that are shown in the screenshot do not change due to a change in localization, it is written in the smal code itself, or there it is registered for parsing this from a Chinese site, there are some dates that are not current yet.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are doing the same stuff as I do. I have Meizu 16Xs (Same CPU as Note 9) and I'm trying to actually mod the Flyme 8.20.1.7 Beta (Chinese firmware)- which is by the way IMHO more stable, at least for my device, than 8.0.0.0A. What I found out is that you can in some way partially "convert" the "Chinese" version of firmware to the "Global" by changing the single parameter in `/system/build.prop` file.

This is the original setting:
`ro.product.locale=zh-CN`

Try to change it to:
`ro.product.locale=en-US`

After restarting your device, this will give you the "Global look", which means:

- In the quick settings on the top-right, there won't be a "notification setting" icon anymore, but will be changed to "cog-wheel" -> which means it's linked to the "Settings"
- In the top left (where you are now seeing the Chinese characters), you will see network carrier info and the current date
- You will be able to change the "Region" from the Settings->Language and Time
- This also unfortunately will disable some options of the Chinese ROM, which means:

  - No Dark (night) mode (doesn't work even if found by app "QuickShortcutMaker" and tried to turn it on)
  - No advanced notification settings available (you won't be able to set the priority of notifications anymore)
  - No Driving mode
  - The Aicy link will disappear from the settings menu (this, I don't know why, will stay disappear also after changing the setting back to the `zh-CN`, and will remain like this until you do the "factory reset", but other mentioned stuff will return back after changing to `zh-CN`...)
  - The Digital Health link won't work
  - The Chinese theme app won't work (can be partially solved by using the `CustomizeCenter.apk` from the Global firmware, but there will be only wallpapers loaded then, no themes) as I found out, that theme app's functionality relies on the setting `zh-CN` or `en-US`.
  - You won't be able to change the lock screen wallpaper by swiping to the right on the lock screen anymore
  - And I think there are also some other things, but I won't be listing everything

For the above-mentioned reasons, I'm rather staying with the option `zh-CN` (as I would like to use these options, which are disabled in the "Global" ROM) and I'm trying to ignore the above-mentioned Chinese characters in the quick settings.

But what I can tell you (hopefully might help) is that I found out what these characters actually probably are: it's probably the Chinese "Lunar Calendar", because, when you go to the settings -> Notification & status bar, there is an option "Lockscreen Lunar Calendar" which you can enable and disable. When you enable it, the same Chinese characters that are shown in the quick settings will be shown on the lock screen.